# <MailSettings> Use deliveryMethods 'Network' and 'SpecifiedPickupDirectory' simultaneously

Tags: asp.net, .net, email, smtpclient, configurationmanager

Exactly as it says on the tin: is it possible to specify both delivery methods in a single configuration? I'd figure it'd be a quick (and cheap) solution to log all e-mail messages that were sent directly by the standard .NET SmtpClient.

What I'm trying to achieve here is a solution in which every e-mail sent by an [defaultly SmtpClient instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1c4h6e2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is both submitted directly to a configured SMTP server and stored in a pickup directory, which merely will act as a storage point for logging the sent e-mail messages.

In other words: Is a configuration as follows possible?

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="source@domain.com">
      <network host="127.0.0.1" />
    </smtp>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
      <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\SmtpLog" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe this is possible in the manner you suggest - see Scott Gutherie's response on http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx (search page for "multiple SMTP servers"). Old message but still current from what I can tell.

I think the system.net mailSettings in web.config are supposed to be considered the *default* settings.

However you can do it in code easily enough (plenty of examples out there) and you could do it so that you can configure in web.config using custom settings.

Comment: Forbes, thanks for your response. These settings being the 'default settings' surely seems reasonable enough to me. I was just wondering (hoping, perhaps?) if there'd be an easier way with the default client. I'll stick around to see what other suggestions may come up for now, but thanks for your thoughts for the time being!